# How to get a raw sequence of reified values in scala macro

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I have a `c.Expr[Seq[T]]` and I want to get a `Seq[c.Expr[T]]` so I can pass it to a library function that processes it and produces a different final result Expr.

I found this answer [explaining how to go in the opposite direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713421/how-to-build-a-dynamic-sequence-in-a-scala-macro) but I can't quite figure out how to invert the process.

`reify { xs.splice.map(x => reify { x }) }` gives me `c.Expr[Seq[c.Expr[T]]]`, which isn't quite right.

Comment: You may have a bit of a problem here: not every `c.Expr[Seq[T]]` can get transformed to a `Seq[c.Expr[T]]`. For example, `(List(1,2,3) ++ List(4,5)).toSeq` is a `c.Expr[Seq[T]]`, but there is no obvious `Seq[c.Expr[T]]` to get from it. Do you maybe mean just targeting expressions of the form `Seq(1,2,3,4)` (so the apply method of the companion object)?

Comment: Also, is there any reason to be using `Expr` instead of `Tree`s? While I think it ought to be possible to return `Seq[Expr[T]]`, it will be much harder than just doing everything with `Tree`.

Comment: In the case of `List1 ++ List2` I'd like to eval the expression, then map `reify` over the resultant `Seq`.

The reason I'm using Expr is to hook into some existing macro helpers in a library.