# (Macro-based?) workaround for "applyDynamic does not support passing a vararg parameter" in Scala

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I'm using [a library](https://github.com/scala-records/scala-records) that makes heavy use of macros and applyDynamic. [The compiler bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9308) that prevents using varargs with applyDynamic has been causing me a lot of pain, and I'm hoping to find a workaround that allows me to pass a dynamic sequence of arguments into an `applyDynamic` that then invokes a macro.

I have tried to write a macro that expands the sequence or splat before invoking `applyDynamic` [with little success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761482/how-to-get-a-raw-sequence-of-reified-values-in-scala-macro), but I'm not very comfortable with Scala macros so I might have been doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I hit this problem while using ScalaJS on this line:

```
literal(seq: _*)
```

the workaround was simply this:

```
literal.applyDynamic("apply")(seq: _*)
```

Explanation: literal (more precisely: scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic.literal) is an object extending scala.Dynamic and the call literal(...) is desuggared to literal.apply(...), which itself should be transformed (if there were no bug) by the compiler to literal.applyDynamic("apply")(...). Well, it's a bit ugly, but one can always remove the sugar himself.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/issues/253) since Scala 2.12.5

Comment: Are you sure? I am still hitting it with Scala.js / Scala 2.13.8 - see https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9308